# Como evitar cambiar el tamaño de las columnas en modo de edicion de un Gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

Tengo el siguiente Gridview, en el cual el usuario puede editar las columnas, pero al editar la tabla las columnas cambian su tamaño, mi pregunta es como evitar eso.
Gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
<Columns>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="27" SortExpression="27">
<EditItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox ID="L27" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("27") %>'></asp:TextBox>
</EditItemTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="Label27" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("27") %>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="28" SortExpression="28">
<EditItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox ID="L28" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("28") %>'></asp:TextBox>
</EditItemTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="Label28" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("28") %>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
...etc
</Columns>
```

Comment: Podrías hacerlo mediante CSS, revisa el código que genera mediante click derecho, inspeccionar elemento.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es porque al renderizar el [webcontrol Textbox](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox) lo hace como un elemento HTML input que por default en los browsers ya tiene un estilo predeterminado (por ejemplo ese ancho).

Entonces deberías utilizar un estilo CSS para "dar el formato que necesitas y requieres" el control HTML input que renderiza el webcontrol Textbox.
Para esto necesitas aplicar en el atributo [CssClass](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.cssclass) la clase CSS que luego lo tienes que colocar en la pagina o recomendacion en el archivo adecuado de  .css de tu proyecto

Ejemplo

```
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="27" SortExpression="27">
    <EditItemTemplate>
         <asp:TextBox ID="L27" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("27") %>' CssClass="ejemplo-input"></asp:TextBox>
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Label ID="Label27" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("27") %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
```

Donde puedes colocar en el archivo .css de tu proyecto (o si tiene varias en el mas adecuado)

```
.ejemplo-input{
    width: 10px;
    padding: 2px 4px;
}
```

Ademas tambien podrias colocar un estilo css a la columna del gridview completa, asi puedes tener un estilo para los bordes o centrado del input dentro del celda de la tabla HTML.

Espero que te sirva de ayuda o guía.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ha servido una solución muy simple,  después de mucho buscar. Saludos